# c++ use static vector in class,compilation error "undefined reference to A::aa" happened

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;  
class A  
{  
public:  
      A(int a);  
      static void print();//静态成员函数  
       static void change();//静态成员函数  
      static std::vector<int> aa;//静态数据成员的声明  
       static const int count;//常量静态数据成员（可以在构造函数中初始化）  
       const int bb;//常量数据成员  
};  

//静态成员的定义+初始化  
const int A::count=25;//静态常量成员定义+初始化  
A::A(int a):bb(a)//常量成员的初始化  
{  

} 

void A::change()
{
     A::aa.push_back(4);
} 
void A::print()  
{  
      change();
      cout<<"count="<<count<<endl;  
      cout<<"aa="<<A::aa[0]<<endl;  
}  

int main()  
{  
      A a(10);  
      A::print();//通过类访问静态成员函数  
      a.print();//通过对象访问静态成员函数 
      return 0; 
}
```

I define a static vector in a class, and try to modify the elements in the vector,

but the compilation error "undefined reference to A::aa"，I want to know how to modify static vector in class

Comment: No you don't define the vector, you only *declare* it. You need to define outside the class, similarly to what you do with the `count` variable.

Comment: Define `A::aa` just like the way you defined `A::count`, though maybe without an initializer for default initialization.

Comment: A new line of `std::vector<int> A::aa;` to "define" it.